# how to update type=file

Tags: php, file, input

how to update type=file

These lines are in my update file. This one works. It echos the $row and i can change it or let it be.

```
<textarea  cols="25" rows="5" name="bio" ><?php echo $row['bio']?> </textarea> </tr></td>
```

Now my question is, how can i get the same thing work with an type="file" ?

```
<input type="file" name="img" accept="image/jpg,image/gif,image/png" /></tr></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that due to browser security reasons.

**But there's something else you can do.**

Display the uploaded pic below the file upload field.If the user wants to change it , let him upload another pic or else just leave it blank.

In the server-side just check if the field is blank or not and do the necessary action.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pre-fill the value of the file upload control (as a security precaution)

Comment: I knew that, but is there no other way to do this?

Comment: If there is, I'd consider reporting it as a security hole to the browser vendor; The better alternate is to present the file that was uploaded, and allow for a different one to be substituted.