# show path of image on update form php

Tags: php, mysql

When populating the fields of an update form how can I show the path to the current image like this
[image]

so that if the user doesn't want to change the image the same image is used. 
This is what the browser displays:
`<input type="file" value="uploads/chaps_B.jpg" name="image_edit"></input>`

I have a feeling my `photopath` in not in scope but unsure how to go about fixing it. All variables populate the form and it saves to the db fine just can't figure out the image path.

```
     if(isset($_POST['update_submit']))
    {
$get_products = $db->prepare("select `photopath` from `item` where 
                            `item_id` = '$get_item' LIMIT 1");
$get_products->execute();
$path= $get_products->fetchColumn(6);

if($_FILES['image_edit']['tmp_name'] != "")
    {
        $edit_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $edit_description =$_POST['item_description'];
        $form_id = $_POST['edit_form_id'];

        $file_dir = "uploads/";
        $image = $file_dir. $_FILES['image_edit']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_edit']['tmp_name'], $image);

        $edit_sql =$db->prepare("UPDATE item SET item_name = '$edit_name', 
                item_description = '$edit_description', 
                photopath ='$image' WHERE item_id = '$form_id'");

        $edit_sql->execute();
        header("Location: manage_items.php");
        exit();

        }
        else
        {
            $edit_name = $_POST['item_name'];
            $edit_description =$_POST['item_description'];
            $form_id = $_POST['edit_form_id'];

            $edit_sql =$db->prepare("UPDATE item SET item_name = '$edit_name', 
                item_description = '$edit_description' 
                 WHERE item_id = '$form_id'");

                $edit_sql->execute();
                header("Location: manage_items.php");
                exit();
            }
```

UPDATE FORM

```
      <form action="item_edit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type = "text" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $item_name ?> "/>
        <textarea name="item_description"><?php echo $item_description ?></textarea>

        <p> <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" width="75" height="75" /></p>
        <input type="file" name="image_edit" />

        <input name="edit_form_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $get_item ?>">
        <p><input type="submit" name="update_submit" value="Update"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="cancel_edit" value="Cancel"/></p>
      </form>
```

DB STRUCTURE

[image]

Comment: Relative path issue most probably. Can you share the path of the page and the path of the uploads dir with respect to web root?

Comment: @Akshay they're in the same directory. uploads is in htdocs folder

Comment: @rogerthat, please let me know if i am off the track, your query is, if user on edit or update page, user can see a already uploaded image name along with chose file button, plus if user dont chose a new image, this image name remain the same in database?

Comment: @m-t you are on track.

Comment: @m-t if the user only wants to edit the name or description and not the image the image should remain the one it is in the db. RIght now when I click `update` photopath` gets set to an empty string

Comment: What you could do to stop it from reinserting into your DB is to check if the `$_POST` for that field is empty, this way you could skip inserting it into the database to.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand So put a different query into the if statement checking if that `$_POST` field is empty?

Comment: This is one way to solving the empty string insertion issue yes, however the query will have to be different so you'll have to write one which does insert the image, and one that excludes it.

Comment: ok what you have to do, in your form <input type="hidden" name=imgEdit" value="<?php echo photopath ?>"/> then of course on edit.php  before if file upload check $image = $_POST['imgEdit']; if user upload the file $image variable automatically update his value otherwise you have the hidden last image name for the same record.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand That method does work. Thanks so much

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand if you post it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: I'll add my last comment on my own answer there.

Comment: @m-t so I would have to compare the current value of `$_POST['imgEdit']` with the hidden value because there will always be an image set.

Comment: This questions answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089020/how-to-update-type-file/19089103#19089103

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When retrieving a single row, you do not have to loop through as you asked in the comment in your code.

As for the database, what exactly are you storing what does your table structure look like?
You could easily save the name of the image in a field and retrieve that and not even get the fullpath ( since there could be more images there )

**EDIT 1**

This is one way to solving the empty string insertion issue yes, however the query will have to be different so you'll have to write one which does insert the image, and one that excludes it

**EDIT 2**

After you retrieve the image path all you'd have to do now is split the string by using PHP's explode, e.g. $aPath = explode('/', $yourDBfield);, this would give you an array with items split on a /, since the file will always be at the end, simply do this: $image = $aPath[(count($aPath)-1)];, this should give you the image.

**EDIT 3**

As requested by the OP,

The main query should include the image update, e.g. when the value set is not empty.

```
$edit_sql =$db->prepare("UPDATE item SET item_name = '$edit_name', 
            item_description = '$edit_description', 
            photopath ='$image' WHERE item_id = '$form_id'");
```

The other query should exclude `photopath` = '$image' e.g.

```
$edit_sql =$db->prepare("UPDATE item SET item_name = '$edit_name', 
            item_description = '$edit_description', 
            WHERE item_id = '$form_id'");
```

You could also, as mentioned in the comments, add the default path, e.g. `$image` (not split) to the value of the field when the page is requested, this way you'd only have to write 1 query, and the image would remain the same if untouched.

Comment: added a photo of the db structure

Comment: What does the fetchColumn method return in your code? It might fetch an array of columns for every row, so you'd have to find out which row is the right one for your user there.

Comment: it returns the path `uploads/filename.extension`

Comment: All you'd have to do now is split the string by using PHP's explode, e.g. `$aPath = explode('/', $yourDBfield);`, this would give you an array with items split on a `/`, since the file will always be at the end, simply do this: `$image = $aPath[(count($aPath)-1)];`, this should give you the image.

Comment: Why not include writing two different queries so its a full answer?

Comment: Done, also added some extra option mentioned by @m-t, which is the better instead of writing 2 queries (e.g. just put the image as default value of the field)